# How to disable iCloud Keychain on the iPhone and prevent bad actor from accessing keychain?

Tags: iphone, keychain

## GOAL

Given the iCloud Keychain is the "keys to the kingdom", I would like to take steps so that if the iPhone is compromised that the bad actor does not have access to the iCloud keychain on the iPhone.  Ideally it would be only possible to enable iCloud KeyChain via 2FA or a trusted Mac / iPad.

This question is prompted by: https://www.wsj.com/articles/stolen-iphone-passcode-security-tips-how-to-protect-data-2c4a3be7

## REAL-WORLD CONTEXT

The [WSJ video](https://www.wsj.com/articles/stolen-iphone-passcode-security-tips-how-to-protect-data-2c4a3be7) indicates that bad actors in major cities are stealing phones to lockout users and gain access to the keychain.  All that is necessary to gain access to the password keychain and lock me out is for the bad actor to:

1. covertly video tape or "shoulder surf" to get gain iPhone password
2. acquire physical access to the iPhone (steal it)
3. **immediately** change the AppleID password

The goal is to prevent / slow the bad actor from gaining access to the iCloud Keychain.

Given the context & goal provided: I hope that readers see the value and would appreciate any help in editing the question pursuant to improving security posture.

Comment: Turn of iCloud keychain sync in iPhone..

Comment: Or simply set a better passcode than a 6-digit number. Also, the article is paywalled so it doesn't work so well as a reference.

Comment: @nohillside. I watched the video and did not read the article.

Comment: This question is now a dupe of the one [already asked/answered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/455404/119271)  (and doesn’t match the title) with the only variance  being gaining access to keychain vs. the whole device.  If an attacker has access to one, they have access to the other.  It’s a distinction without a difference.

Comment: The WSJ is partially alarmistic, the simple answer is "set a better passcode which can't be memorized by shoulder surfing". If you do that, all the other points become kind of irrelevant.